# Quartz Scheduler preemptive trigger priority

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Is it possible to implement some kind of "preemptive" behavior linked to trigger priorities?

I mean, I want a high-priority trigger to interrupt the currently running low-priority job, and run in its place.

I'd like to go further and not just compare trigger priorities on the same job, but on different jobs trying to work on the same "resource", not at the same time but at overlapping times (assuming the "work" takes time to complete).

I didn't find anything "out of the box". Did anyone ever implement something similar?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution so far (imports removed). Any warnings or improvements?

```
//
// AN EXAMPLE JOB CLASS
//

public class DevJob implements InterruptableJob {
    private final transient Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    AtomicReference<Thread> jobThreadHolder = new AtomicReference<Thread>();

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        String triggerName = jobExecutionContext.getTrigger().getKey().toString();
        String jobName = jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getKey().toString();
        log.debug("Executing Job {}-{} ", triggerName, jobName);
        jobThreadHolder.set(Thread.currentThread());
        JobDataMap jobDataMap = jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
        int duration = jobDataMap.getInt("duration");
        try {
            log.debug("Job {}-{} works for {}s...", triggerName, jobName, duration);
            Thread.sleep(duration*1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.debug("Job {}-{} interrupted", triggerName, jobName);
            PreemptiveVolatileQueueQuartzListener.setInterrupted(jobExecutionContext);
        } finally {
            log.debug("Job {}-{} terminates", triggerName, jobName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void interrupt() throws UnableToInterruptJobException {
         Thread thread = jobThreadHolder.getAndSet(null);
         if (thread != null) {
             thread.interrupt();
         }
    }
}


//
// IMPLEMENTATION FOR JOB PREEMPTION
//

/**
 * This class implements a priority policy for jobs in the same thread group.
 * When a new job starts, it will check if another job in the same thread group is already running.
 * In such a case it compares trigger priorities. The job with lower priority is put in a wait queue for the thread group,
 * but only if another instance with the same jobKey is not in the queue already.
 * When the running job terminates, a new job is pulled from the queue based on priority and timestamp: for equal
 * priorities, the older one is executed.
 * If a job has been interrupted MAX_RESCHEDULINGS times, it will ignore any further interruptions.
 * A job must implement InterruptableJob and periodically call checkInterruptRequested() if it can be interrupted by a
 * higher priority job; it could ignore interruptions, in which case the higher priority job will execute only after 
 * its natural termination. 
 */
public class PreemptiveVolatileQueueQuartzListener implements JobListener, TriggerListener {
    private final transient Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    // The number of times that a low priority job can be preempted by any high priority job before it ignores preemption
    private static final int MAX_RESCHEDULINGS = 20; 

    // This map holds the pointer to the current running job and its deferred queue, for a given thread group
    private Map<String, RunningJobHolder> runningJobs = new HashMap<>(); // triggerGroup -> RunningJob

    private static final String INTERRUPTED_FLAG = "PREEMPT_INTERRUPTED";
    private static final String INTERRUPTREQUESTED_FLAG = "PREEMPT_INTERRUPTREQUESTED";
    static final String JOB_ORIG_KEY = "PREEMPT_JOBORIGKEY";

    /**
     * Call this method to notify a job that an interruption has been requested. It should tipically be called
     * in the InterruptableJob.interrupt() method. The job will then have to programmatically check this flag with checkInterruptRequested()
     * and exit if the result is true.
     */
    public final static void requestInterrupt(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) {
        jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().put(INTERRUPTREQUESTED_FLAG, true);
    }

    /**
     * Call this method in a job to check if an interruption has been requested. If the result is true, the "interrupted" flag
     * will be set to true and the job should exit immediately
     * because it will be rescheduled after the interrupting job has finished.
     * @param jobExecutionContext can be null if the check should not be performed
     * @return true if the interruption was requested
     */
    public final static boolean checkInterruptRequested(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (jobExecutionContext!=null) {
            try {
                result = jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().getBoolean(INTERRUPTREQUESTED_FLAG);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Ignore, stay false
            }
            if (result) {
                setInterrupted(jobExecutionContext);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Call this method in a job when catching an InterruptedException if not rethrowing a JobExecutionException
     * @param jobExecutionContext
     */
    public final static void setInterrupted(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) {
        jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().put(INTERRUPTED_FLAG, true);
    }

    private final boolean isInterrupted(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) {
        try {
            return true==jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().getBoolean(INTERRUPTED_FLAG);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private final void clearInterrupted(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) {
        jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().remove(INTERRUPTREQUESTED_FLAG);
        jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().remove(INTERRUPTED_FLAG);
    }

    /**
     * This method decides if a job has to start or be queued for later.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean vetoJobExecution(Trigger startingTrigger, JobExecutionContext startingJobContext) {
        log.debug("Calculating veto for job {}", makeJobString(startingTrigger));
        boolean veto = false;
        String preemptedGroup = startingTrigger.getKey().getGroup();
        synchronized (runningJobs) {
            veto = calcVeto(startingTrigger, preemptedGroup, startingJobContext);
        }
        log.debug("veto={} for job {}", veto, makeJobString(startingTrigger));
        return veto;
    }

    private boolean calcVeto(Trigger startingTrigger, String preemptedGroup, JobExecutionContext startingJobContext) {
        final boolean VETO = true;
        final boolean NOVETO = false;
        int startingJobPriority = startingTrigger.getPriority();
        RunningJobHolder runningJobHolder = runningJobs.get(preemptedGroup);
        if (runningJobHolder==null) {
            // No conflicting job is running - just start it
            runningJobHolder = new RunningJobHolder();
            runningJobs.put(preemptedGroup, runningJobHolder);
            PrioritizedJob newJob = runningJobHolder.setActiveJob(startingJobPriority, startingTrigger, startingJobContext);
            log.debug("Starting new job {} with nothing in the same group", newJob);
            return NOVETO;
        }

        // Check that the current job isn't a job that has just been pulled from the queue and activated
        boolean sameTrigger = startingTrigger.equals(runningJobHolder.activeJob.trigger);
        if (sameTrigger) {
            // runningJobHolder.activeJob has been set in triggerComplete but the trigger didn't fire until now
            log.debug("Starting trigger {} is the same as the active one", startingTrigger.getKey());
            return NOVETO; 
        }

        // Check that the starting job is not already running and is not already queued, because we don't want
        // jobs to accumulate in the queue (a design choice)
        if (runningJobHolder.isInHolder(startingTrigger)) {
            log.debug("Starting job {} is queued already (maybe with a different trigger)", makeJobString(startingTrigger));
            return VETO;
        }

        // A job for this triggerGroup is already running and is not the same as the one trying to start and is not in the queue already.
        // The starting job is therefore queued, ready to be started, regardless of the priority.
        PrioritizedJob newJob = runningJobHolder.queueJob(startingJobPriority, startingTrigger, startingJobContext);
        log.debug("New job {} queued", newJob);
        printQueue(runningJobHolder); // Debug

        if (startingJobPriority>runningJobHolder.activeJob.priority) {
            if (runningJobHolder.activeJob.reschedulings >= MAX_RESCHEDULINGS) {
                // When a job has been preempted too many times, it is left alone even if at lower priority
                log.debug("New job {} does not interrupt job {} of lower priority because its reschedulings are {}", newJob, runningJobHolder.activeJob, runningJobHolder.activeJob.reschedulings);
            } else {
                // The starting job has a higher priority than the current running job, which needs to be interrupted.
                // The new job will take the place of the running job later, because it has been added to the queue already.
                // If the running job doesn't react to the interruption, it will complete normally and let the next job in 
                // the queue to proceed.
                log.debug("New job {} interrupts job {} of lower priority", newJob, runningJobHolder.activeJob);
                try {
                    Scheduler scheduler = startingJobContext.getScheduler();
                    scheduler.interrupt(runningJobHolder.getJobKey());
                } catch (UnableToInterruptJobException e) {
                    log.error("Can't interrupt job {} for higher-priority job {} that will have to wait", runningJobHolder.activeJob, newJob);
                }
            }
        }
        return VETO;
    }

    /**
     * The interrupt() method of a InterruptableJob should issue a thread.interrupt() on the job thread,
     * and if not handled already, the resulting InterruptedException will be handled here.
     */
    @Override
    public void jobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException) {
        // Just in case a job throws InterruptedException when interrupted.
        // Raise a flag if the job was interrupted with InterruptedException
        if (jobException!=null && jobException.getCause() instanceof InterruptedException) {
            PreemptiveVolatileQueueQuartzListener.setInterrupted(context);
        }
    }

    // Debug method
    private void printQueue(RunningJobHolder runningJobHolder) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            PriorityQueue<PrioritizedJob> clone = new PriorityQueue<PrioritizedJob>();
            clone.addAll(runningJobHolder.jobQueue);
            log.debug("Priority Queue: {}", clone.isEmpty()?"empty":"");
            while (!clone.isEmpty()) {
                PrioritizedJob job = clone.poll();
                String jobKey = (String) job.trigger.getJobDataMap().getOrDefault(PreemptiveVolatileQueueQuartzListener.JOB_ORIG_KEY, job.trigger.getJobKey().toString());
                log.debug("- {} [{}] reschedulings={}", job, jobKey, job.reschedulings);
            }
        }
    }

    // When a job finishes execution, a new one is started if the queue is not empty
    private boolean startNextJobInQueue(PrioritizedJob terminatedJob, RunningJobHolder runningJobHolder, String preemptedGroup, Trigger usedTrigger, JobExecutionContext context) {
        PrioritizedJob queuedJob = runningJobHolder.jobQueue.poll(); // Remove from queue
        if (queuedJob!=null) {          //
            log.debug("Starting next job in queue {} after job {} finished", queuedJob, terminatedJob);
            // The job must be cloned with a new trigger to execute immediately.
            // Can't reuse the existing jobDetail with a new trigger because for some reason when the original trigger has
            // finished all invocations, the following exception is thrown when trying to start the new trigger:
            // org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: The job (xxx) referenced by the trigger does not exist. 
            JobDataMap jobDataMap = queuedJob.jobDetail.getJobDataMap();
            JobDataMap triggerJobDataMap = queuedJob.trigger.getJobDataMap();
            JobDataMap newTriggerJobDataMap = new JobDataMap(triggerJobDataMap);
            // Need to store the original jobKey, used to check if a starting job is already in the queue. I can't use the normal
            // jobKey because, when a job is cloned here, its key must be changed in order to store it without a "job already exists" exception.
            String jobOrigKey = (String) triggerJobDataMap.getOrDefault(JOB_ORIG_KEY, queuedJob.jobDetail.getKey().toString());
            newTriggerJobDataMap.put(JOB_ORIG_KEY, jobOrigKey);
            JobDetail newJob = JobBuilder.newJob(queuedJob.jobDetail.getJobClass())
                .withIdentity(makePreemptedId(queuedJob.jobDetail.getKey().getName()), queuedJob.jobDetail.getKey().getGroup())
                .requestRecovery(queuedJob.jobDetail.requestsRecovery())
                .storeDurably(queuedJob.jobDetail.isDurable())
                .withDescription(queuedJob.jobDetail.getDescription())
                .usingJobData(jobDataMap)
                .build();
            Trigger newTrigger = newTrigger()
                .withPriority(queuedJob.priority)
                .withIdentity(makePreemptedId(queuedJob.trigger.getKey().getName()), preemptedGroup)
                .usingJobData(newTriggerJobDataMap)
                .withDescription(queuedJob.trigger.getDescription())
                .startNow()
                .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                    // A misfire occurs if a persistent trigger “misses” its firing time because 
                    // of the scheduler being shutdown, or because there are no available threads
                    .withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow() // (Not sure is correct)
                    )            
                .build();
            try {
                context.getScheduler().scheduleJob(newJob, newTrigger);
                log.debug("Job {} from queue rescheduled to start now as {}", queuedJob, makeJobString(newTrigger));
                queuedJob.reschedulings++;
                queuedJob.trigger = newTrigger;
                queuedJob.jobDetail = newJob;
                runningJobHolder.activeJob = queuedJob;
                return true;
            } catch (SchedulerException e) {
                log.error("Failed to start queued job {}", queuedJob, e);
                runningJobHolder.activeJob = null;
                return false;
            }
        }       
        return false;
    }

    private String makeJobString(Trigger trigger) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(trigger.getKey().toString());
        sb.append("-").append(trigger.getJobKey().toString());
        return sb.toString();
    }

    // Each time a job is rescheduled with a new trigger, their names are changed to a (hopefully) unique string
    private String makePreemptedId(String oldName) {
        final String marker = "_p_r_e_";
        long random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(999888777L);
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(Long.toString(random)); // nnn
        int pos = oldName.indexOf(marker);
        if (pos>-1) {
            result.append(oldName.substring(pos));
        } else {
            result.append(marker).append(oldName);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    // Called when a job finishes execution
    @Override
    public void triggerComplete(Trigger usedTrigger, JobExecutionContext context, CompletedExecutionInstruction completedExecutionInstruction) {
        boolean interruptedJob = isInterrupted(context);
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            if (interruptedJob) {
                log.debug("Interrupted job {}", makeJobString(usedTrigger));
            } else {
                log.debug("Terminated job {}", makeJobString(usedTrigger));
            }
        }
        String preemptedGroup = usedTrigger.getKey().getGroup();
        synchronized (runningJobs) {
            RunningJobHolder runningJobHolder = runningJobs.get(preemptedGroup);
            // Check that the activeJob is also the one that just terminated - for consistency
            if (runningJobHolder==null || !runningJobHolder.getJobKey().equals(context.getJobDetail().getKey())) {
                // Should never happen if there aren't any bugs
                log.error("Internal Error: the job in triggerComplete {} is not the active job {} for group {} (skipping)",
                    makeJobString(usedTrigger),
                    runningJobHolder==null?null:runningJobHolder.activeJob,
                    preemptedGroup);
                return;
            }
            printQueue(runningJobHolder);
            PrioritizedJob terminatedJob = runningJobHolder.activeJob;
            clearInterrupted(context);
            runningJobHolder.activeJob = null;
            // Start the next queued job if any. Do it in a loop because the next job might not start 
            // properly and this would otherwise prevent the other queued jobs from starting. 
            boolean started = false;
            while (!started && !runningJobHolder.jobQueue.isEmpty()) {
                started = startNextJobInQueue(terminatedJob, runningJobHolder, preemptedGroup, usedTrigger, context);
                if (interruptedJob && (started || runningJobHolder.jobQueue.isEmpty())) {
                    // It was an interrupted lower-priority job, so put it in the queue 
                    log.debug("Interrupted job {} added to job queue for rescheduling", terminatedJob);
                    runningJobHolder.addToQueue(terminatedJob);
                    interruptedJob=false;
                }
            }
            printQueue(runningJobHolder);
            if (runningJobHolder.jobQueue.isEmpty() && runningJobHolder.activeJob == null) {
                // The current terminated job was the last one in the trigger group, so we can clean up
                log.debug("Job {} ended with an empty proprity queue", terminatedJob);
                runningJobs.remove(preemptedGroup);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void triggerFired(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context) {
    }

    @Override
    public void triggerMisfired(Trigger trigger) {
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

    @Override
    public void jobToBeExecuted(JobExecutionContext context) {
    }

    @Override
    public void jobExecutionVetoed(JobExecutionContext context) {
    }
}


//
// RELATED CLASSES
//


/**
 * A job with associated priority and timestamp
 *
 */
class PrioritizedJob implements Comparable<PrioritizedJob> {
    int priority;
    long creationTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis(); // To prevent same-priority elements to age
    Trigger trigger;
    JobDetail jobDetail; // Needed to create a new job when rescheduling after pulling from the queue
    int reschedulings = 0; // Number of times the job has been put back in the queue because preempted by a higher-priority job

    @Override
    public int compareTo(PrioritizedJob o) {
        // Smallest PrioritizedJob goes first, so priority check must be inverted because higher priority goes first
        int comparison = -(new Integer(this.priority).compareTo(o.priority));
        if (comparison==0) {
            // lower timestamp is higher priority
            comparison = new Long(this.creationTimestamp).compareTo(o.creationTimestamp);
        }
        return comparison;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        result.append(trigger.getKey()).append("-").append(trigger.getJobKey()).append("(").append(priority).append(")");
        return result.toString();
    }
}


/**
 * Holds the current running job definition for a given trigger group
 */
class RunningJobHolder {
    PrioritizedJob activeJob; // The running  job
    // This queue holds all jobs of the same thread group that tried to start while this job was running.
    // They are sorted by priority and timestamp.
    // The head of the queue might contain a higher-priority job that has been put in the queue while waiting for
    // the active job to handle the interruption
    PriorityQueue<PrioritizedJob> jobQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(); 

    JobKey getJobKey() {
        return activeJob.trigger.getJobKey();
    }

    /**
     * Create a new PrioritizedJob and set it as active
     * @param startingJobPriority
     * @param startingTrigger
     * @param startingJobContext
     * @return the new PrioritizedJob
     */
    PrioritizedJob setActiveJob(int startingJobPriority, Trigger startingTrigger, JobExecutionContext startingJobContext) {
        PrioritizedJob newJob = new PrioritizedJob();
        newJob.priority = startingJobPriority;
        newJob.trigger = startingTrigger;
        newJob.jobDetail = startingJobContext.getJobDetail();
        this.activeJob = newJob;
        return newJob;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new PrioritizedJob and add it to the queue
     * @param startingJobPriority
     * @param startingTrigger
     * @param startingJobContext
     * @return the new PrioritizedJob
     */
    PrioritizedJob queueJob(int startingJobPriority, Trigger startingTrigger, JobExecutionContext startingJobContext) {
        PrioritizedJob newJob = new PrioritizedJob();
        newJob.priority = startingJobPriority;
        newJob.trigger = startingTrigger;
        newJob.jobDetail = startingJobContext.getJobDetail();
        addToQueue(newJob);
        return newJob;
    }

    /**
     * Compares job keys, first by fetching the original job key stored in the trigger JobDataMap, then by using the job's own key
     * @param trigger
     * @param prioritizedJob
     * @return
     */
    private boolean equalKeys(Trigger trigger, PrioritizedJob prioritizedJob) {
        String triggerJobKeyToCheck = (String) trigger.getJobDataMap().getOrDefault(PreemptiveVolatileQueueQuartzListener.JOB_ORIG_KEY, trigger.getJobKey().toString()); 
        String prioritizedJobKeyToCheck = (String) prioritizedJob.trigger.getJobDataMap().getOrDefault(PreemptiveVolatileQueueQuartzListener.JOB_ORIG_KEY, prioritizedJob.trigger.getJobKey().toString());
        return triggerJobKeyToCheck.equals(prioritizedJobKeyToCheck);
    }

    /**
     * Check if the job in a trigger has already been queued (or is the active one) by comparing the job key
     * @param trigger
     * @return
     */
    boolean isInHolder(Trigger trigger) {
        if (equalKeys(trigger, activeJob)) {
            return true;
        }
        for (PrioritizedJob prioritizedJob : jobQueue) {
            if (equalKeys(trigger, prioritizedJob)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    void addToQueue(PrioritizedJob prioritizedJob) {
        jobQueue.add(prioritizedJob);
    }
}
```

Comment: I made a much more complicated version of the above code, after which I decided that it was much simpler to develop my own scheduler!

Comment: At least you are ready to write your own scheduler now :) Actually interrupting an active trigger sounds a little bit strange. Here is how i solved the problem; I stored the triggered jobs on a persistent priority queue when they get triggered and consumed them according to their priority. Increased the dependency but decreased the headache :)